# Applying a php function to one column after PDOStatement::fetchAll()

Tags: php, mysql, twig

Lets say I have this code:

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

which outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => pear
            [0] => pear
            [colour] => green
            [1] => green
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => watermelon
            [0] => watermelon
            [colour] => pink
            [1] => pink
        )

)
```

before this code, I have designed the following simple function:

```
function changecolour($data){
  if($data == 'pink'){ $data = 'red'; }
  return $data
}
```

The Question:
How can I apply the function to the array with the key `[colour]` only (apply to one column from the database) and fix the whole array with the new column? Also, what are the implications that your method could result in, if the array is large for example? How would you suggest to apply a function on one column of a mysql table if you are using twig?

Comment: Try using array_filter php function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is to update the query like this:

```
SELECT name, IF(colour='pink','red',color) FROM fruit
```

On the other hand, if it is absolutely necessary to use the described function, you you can do so:

```
$result = array_map(function($row) {
    $row['color'] = changecolour($row['color']);
    return $row;
});
```

Or with foreach loop:

```
foreach ($result as &$row) {
        $row['color'] = changecolour($row['color']);
}
```

**UPD**: On the second thought you can add new function for a broader case:

```
function apply_column($rows, $column, $function) {
    foreach ($rows as &$row) {
        $row[$column] = $function($row[$column]);
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

And use it:

```
$result = apply_column($result, 'color', 'changecolour');
```